# php - loop that compares user input against table

Tags: php

I have a form a user fills in and the action page it goes to basically just turns all the post_variables into session_variables and the it queries the database for email addresses that  might match the email adr the user submitted. If the number of rows where a match is found equals one or more, i want to direct the user to a page that tells them the email is already in use, else they will direct to another php page where all the info will be written into the database.

For some reason it's not working - php(or mysql) does not find any matches, even though there are rows in the table with the same address.

Hope someone can point this out for me. I use php 5.0 on LAMP.

here is the code on the page that the form "actions" to:

```
     <?PHP
 session_start();

 $dbhost = 'somewhere.net';
 $dbuser = 'someUser';
 $dbpass = 'pass'
 $dbname = 'medrecruit';


 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error($conn));
 mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error($conn));

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
 $_SESSION['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
 $_SESSION['smacker'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['smacker']);
 $_SESSION['password'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confpassword']);
 $_SESSION['surname'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
 $_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
 $_SESSION['age'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
 $_SESSION['nationality'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nationality']);
 $_SESSION['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
 $_SESSION['telnr'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telnr']);
 $_SESSION['special'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['special']);
 $_SESSION['qf1'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf1']);
 $_SESSION['qf2'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf2']);
 $_SESSION['qf3'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf3']);
 $_SESSION['qf4'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf4']);
 $_SESSION['qf5'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf5']);
 $_SESSION['qf6'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf6']);
 $_SESSION['qf7'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf7']);
 $_SESSION['qf8'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf8']);
 $_SESSION['qf9'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf9']);
 $_SESSION['qf10'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qf10']);
 $_SESSION['cv'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cv']);
 $_SESSION['activationkey'] =  mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand() . mt_rand();

 $newmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


 $query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = '$newmail'";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1){
   header("Location: noemail.html");
   }
   header("Location: insert.php");

 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your quotes around the wrong way here, for a start:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = ".$_POST["email"]."';
```

Single quotes (') are not interpolated. Double quotes (') are. Also, you should not be using `$_POST["email"]` directly in your query - it's a security hole and open to abuse. I assume you know this, as you're already using `$newemail` to hold an escaped version. Try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email = '$newmail'";
```

Comment: I updated the code, still not working though. I think something is wrong where I extract the result and compare the email adr..

Comment: Looks like this is back to front: `if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1){ header("Location: noemail.html");` You're going to `noemail.html` if there is one result or more.

Comment: I see what you mean, but it should be like that. nomail.html is  the page that tells the user his address is already in use.

Comment: $newmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


$query = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM employee WHERE email = '$newmail' LIMIT 1", $conn) or die(mysql_error());
  if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
   header("Location: nomail.html");
         }      else
         {
   header("Location: insert.php");      
         }